# Using Spring Actuator with Spring CommandLineRunner application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am developing a TCP socket server application in java using Spring Boot. Eventhough, I am not using the spring-boot-starter-web dependency, I still would like to benefit from the actuator endpoint to monitor the application using external monitoring tool like prometheus.

A minimal equivalent application would be:

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

DemoApplication.java

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

SpringBootConsoleApplication.java

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpringBootConsoleApplication
    implements CommandLineRunner {

  private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
      .getLogger(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class);


  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    LOG.info("EXECUTING : command line runner");
    int i = 0;
    while(true) {
      LOG.info("iteration: {}", i++);
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  jmx:
    enabled: true

management:
  endpoints:
    jmx:
      unique-names: true
      exposure:
        include: '*'
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
    health:
      show-details: always
```

Using jconsole, I can get the actuator data via JMX, but how to get them from the actuator rest endpoint?

Are there some missing (or unnecessary) config in the `application.yml` or missing dependencies?

I have read the other posts:

- [how could access actuator endpoints in non-web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546884/how-could-access-actuator-endpoints-in-non-web-application)
- [Spring boot actuator for commandline runner application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74751421/spring-boot-actuator-for-commandline-runner-application)

without managing to make the rest actuator working on my application.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a command line application there is no web server included and therefore also no Actuator REST endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Other posts suggested that it was possible though. What would be the minimal dependencies to activate the actuator endpoint?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-web But IMHO this doesn't make sense.